# How do I move the camera in any perspective mode so the reference image doesn't vanish?

Tags: camera, image

I use the Shift + F method to move my camera when I'm modeling(which makes my background image/reference vanish) but lately I watched this person who could move the camera without the BG image vanishing:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iI3zaenro-M

This would be incredibly helpful but I simply don't know how to do that and my google searches have turned up nothing, so I really need some help from the community on this :)

Comment: (If I understand correctly) You are going into perspective mode, which hides background images. Stay in orthographic (Numpad 5) and use the numpad (numpad 1, 3, 7) to switch the camera angle, and the background image will stay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your background image will vanish as soon as you leave orthographic view or rotate the camera to an angle the background image isn´t set for.

Just stay in orthographic view (<kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>) and use Front View (<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>), Side View (<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>) and Top View (<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>) to change the directions; for the opposite of those views press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as well.

To move your current view without rotating just press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and drag your view with <kbd>Middle Mouse Button</kbd>

Comment: Omg thank you so much, this is seriously a big help and saves so much farting around! :D